# Use MSBuild Properties in T4 Templates

Tags: t4, msbuild-4.0

I am using MSBuild to generate some files using T4 and I was wondering if it would be possible to reference and use MSBuild properties within the T4 template?

I want to do something like this snippet:

`Revision: <#=$(Revision)#>`

This throws an error:

`error CS1056: Compiling transformation: Unexpected character '$'`

I'd prefer not to have to wrap the properties in a custom DLL and reference a C# class as a T4 property.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to pass $(Revision) value via [TextTransform command line -a option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126245.aspx).

Add something like this into your template:

```
      [<#= this.Host.ResolveParameterValue("", "", "RevisionParameter") #>]
```

And into MsBuild script:

```
    TextTransform -a !!RevisionParameter!$(Revision)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`ResolveAssemblyReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/bb126367%28v%3Dvs.110%29), for example :

```
Revision: <#=Host.ResolveAssemblyReference("$(Revision)")#>
```