# How to access custom project properties from a T4 template?

Tags: t4, csproj

In VS 2010, is it possible to access a custom project property from a T4 template, e.g. in an `Assembly` directive?

I can't manage to access such properties, e.g. defined in a `<PropertyGroup>` in my .csproj file. Accessing predefined VS macros (like `$(SolutionDir)` or `$(ConfigurationName)`) works though.

Thanks and best regards,
Oliver

Comment: As I noticed now, VS macros like `$(SolutionDir)` or `$(ConfigurationName)` don't work either when the T4 transformation runs as a MSBuild step. They only work when I run the transformation manually in the Visual Studio environment.

Is it possible to access these macros in a MSBuild environment?

Comment: is this for run-time,compile-time, or design-time T4?

Comment: It is for compile-time T4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a file containing the `Assembly` directive as a pre-build step (which can access the environment variables). In all my T4 templates I can then include this auto-generated file which loads the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can have the [msbuild file set an environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267938/msbuild-how-to-set-environment-variables) which can then be pulled in via T4.

Also [Use MSBuild Properties in T4 Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861262/use-msbuild-properties-in-t4-templates) there's a command-line way to do it.