# Get ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in T4 Template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, environment-variables, t4

Within a T4 Template, I'm having trouble getting the value for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in my project, currently set to "Development".

```
string env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
```

This appears to run fine, but pulls back null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my understanding, T4 is always Design Time -> Developement Environment. Therefore I am not sure, what exactly you are trying to do.

The environment variable is set in *Properties/launchSettings.json* and will be loaded if you start your project via Visual Studio:

```
"environmentVariables": {
  "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
}
```

Of course, T4 doesn't load the Variables configured in *launchSettings.json*, since it is not the application itself. You could parse the file manualy, or set the environment variable yourself in Windows or [probably in MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19062596/2441442).

Comment: Actually, that's perfect, that gives me what I need to load my appsettings.Development.json file.  I kinda figured Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable() would be a run-time thing, just wasn't sure how else to get at the variable.  Thanks!

Comment: @BrettRossier Glad I was able to help. But a word of warning: If you generate Code, where the generation strategy is different, depending on a variable, it could be a sign, you have an design problem. If possible review it carefully and probably post a question on CodeReview.SE

Comment: In this instance, I'm generating a ViewModel class from database entries that *should* be the same across Development and Production.  By basing it on that variable, the build in Staging should fail if schema/data hasn't been updated yet.  Just serves as an early warning.